# Click a button to get alert in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This is my wordpress listing site. Here i want to get alert popup when i click Save & Preview button.
so please give me a proper solution for this.

wp:

[image]

Comment: Here is an example - https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_click

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Elementor then it is very easy. use Elementor popup and create popup which you want then add popup link to your "save and preview" button.

Answer (score 0):

Put this one at end of the code before  tag or put in footer file of your child theme

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#btnsave').click(function() { // #btnsave is element ID, you can replace with element ID or Class
        alert('Hello');
    });
});
</script>
```